# retrieve all the min value in priceColumn android SQLite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i have product table inside database. Inside productTable have productBar and price.I want to get all the min price and display inside the listView .Let say inside the producttable have three product with price RM1 (lower) . But my problem is it only display last Column of  productPrice inside listView.

```
public Cursor getMinPrice(String barcode1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] args={barcode1};
        String name="";
        Cursor c= database.rawQuery("SELECT " + SQLiteHelper.product_id
                + " as _id, "+SQLiteHelper.productName+","+SQLiteHelper.productQtty+","+SQLiteHelper.product_ShoppingF+" ,"+SQLiteHelper.product_FId+" ,MIN("+SQLiteHelper.productPrice+") FROM "+SQLiteHelper.productTable+" WHERE  "+SQLiteHelper.productBar+ "=?",args);

        //return database.query(SQLiteHelper.productTable,null, "price=(SELECT MAX("+SQLiteHelper.productPrice+"))", null, null, null, null);
        try{
        c.moveToFirst();



            return c;
        }finally{

        }






    }


  public String getProductNameLower(Cursor c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return((c.getString(1)));
    }
}
```

is it any wrong in my query ?because it only get last column of min price. Hope anybody can guide me ...thank you ..

Comment: I think you need to add group by productBar to end of your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `MIN()`, your query searches for a record containing the minimum price, and returns that record.

If you want to have more than one record, use a query like this, which returns the records with the three smallest prices:

```
SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY price LIMIT 3
```

Comment: This query doesn't use `MIN()`. What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query to get the minimum price

```
SELECT MIN(productPrice)FROM productTable
```